# Can RFC 6570 URI Templates encode space separators for optional parameters?

Tags: java, javascript, url, uritemplate

I'm working with the US Census API ([examples](http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1/examples.html)), in which there are optional parameters, which are space-separated.  I needed a general-purpose URL templating mechanism, and Google led me to RFC 6570 and its implementations.

But as I understand it, RFC 6570 can't template a query substring like:

```
...&in=state:02+county:170&...
```

where "county" may be undefined and should be omitted if so, along with the preceding "+"-encoded space, to leave just

```
...&in=state:02&...
```

Can RFC 6570 encode this?

If not, is there an alternative templating syntax for general-purpose URI templating in common use I should consider that's implemented in Javascript and maybe Java?

Is use of a "+" to delimit query sub-elements, as done here, common, or extremely quirky?  (I'm asking about frequency-of-use, not whether it's wise!)  Is RFC 6570 too restrictive for an application where one is not in control of the URI query syntaxes used?

UPDATE

I see two problems: one is the "+" separator, and the other is the use of "**:**" in e.g. "state:02", which I don't see how to do either.